# Recording equipment for game sounds

Tags: audio, sound, sound-effects

I was wondering if anybody knows about any good pieces of equipment fit for recording sound effects for games.
If you can, also tell please me the price range for professional equipment.

Comment: Haven't done any extensive sound recording yet but a noise free microphone and some knowledge with a sound auditing software is all it takes to get up and running. What exactly you want to know?

Comment: You might get better answers over at http://avp.stackexchange.com/. However, if you're not too worried about realism, then just get a basic microphone, fire up Audacity and play around with some of the effects. Also, I feel that this is a bit too broad. If you could give us some examples of what types of effects you're after, then we could help out more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recording sound effects is an expensive process, and requires sound-proofing, expensive equipment and professional actors / real life objects.

Game studios and Film studios generally have huge sound banks from which they take basic sounds and mix, filter, compress and generally manipulate the basic sounds to their needs.

[The Wilhelm Scream](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cdbYsoEasio) is a great example of re-use of sound effects in films: I never noticed it until I saw this video and now I hear it everywhere!

I believe that a lot of the work a Sound Designer has to do is find the right sounds from a sound bank and mess about with them until they're perfect for the game. This is why I think that with any basic recording equipment you could start recording and just use noise filters and compression to get some ok quality sounds. If you're starting off the best thing to know is how to use filters and apply sounds to a certain situation.

Software-wise I know [SoundForge](http://www.sonycreativesoftware.com/soundforgesoftware) is widely used for sound editing, I really think it's a great, but expensive tool. For other software you can search the site, but [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is a good free sound editing tool.

Equipment-wise you'd be best going to a local store and asking for professional advice; the price is dependant on your budget and the target of what you want to do exactly.

Answer (score 1):

To record sound effects, you need a decent recording device and microphone. You **do not need to spend a lot of money**. For example, here is a nice [Tascam stereo mic for iPhone](http://tascam.com/product/im2/) around $69 dollars. Couple that with a good audio editor on a computer or [iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fire-field-recorder/id309378684?mt=8) and you are ready to go. Companies like Blue Microphones also make inexpensive high quality microphones and audio interfaces  for PC or Mac which you can use to record your sounds.